# openssl decrypt file

Tags: php, file, openssl

Hopefully someone knows the answer...

**BACKGROUND**

I have created a small routine in PHP that encrypts a (large) file using the cipher AES, key length 256bits and the block cipher CBC.
Now, because the file is very large I could not feed the whole file to the encrypt routine (memory overflow) so I had to chunk the file in 4128 bytes at a time and to send each block to the encrypt routine. The resulted encrypted blocks become 4128+16 bytes long (16 from AES padding) and I wrote them into a file (a chain of blocks => encrypted file).

Normally, if I would encrypt that file via openssl it would pad only the last block. In my case, because I had to read one block at a time, I had to do it each block (remember that AES pads with 128bits as AES uses a fixed block of 128bits).

**THE PROBLEM**

I am trying to decrypt this file by using the openssl utility. The problem is that the openssl has no idea that my encrypted file is not padded only at the end but every block (of 4128+16 bytes). So it will remove the last block padding but every other block contains 16 bytes more (let's call them garbage). If I encode a plain-text file I would see the garbage and I would understand that's a decryption problem. If the file is binary (a picture, an executable, whatever) then the file probably will not be interpreted/loaded.

**THE QUESTION**

Does openssl utility have any option that allows me to tell it that the input file must be decoded in blocks of X-bytes at a time instead the whole file?
Do you see any other solution for this kind of problem?

Comment: You don't need to, and should not, encrypt data in chunks like this. Any sane crypto API provides functions to start encrypting a data stream (typically called `something_encrypt_init` or some such), to append data to the stream (`something_encrypt_update`), and to close the stream (`something_encrypt_final`). Looking at the [PHP OpenSSL API](http://php.net/manual/en/book.openssl.php), if that's what you used, it appears badly designed. The fix is to use a better-designed API.

Comment: Also read http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~daw/teaching/cs261-f12/misc/if.html . You may want to enlist the help of [so] or [security.se] to design your program correctly. For example, are you sure you don't need to verify data integrity (i.e. don't you care if an adversary gives you fake data)?

Comment: I have to use PHP as-is. Obviously the OpenSSL API is badly implemented, that's why I was stuck and called for cavalry. Finally I decided to go with encryption in chunks - as a temporary workaround - and regarding the openssl I wrote a small script that involves the use of dd + openssl (Linux only or WinOS+Cygwin). If anyone interested then read this: http://mynixworld.info/2015/04/05/php-openssl-aes-encryption/